# Term for when someone falsely accuses another of misdeeds that they are actually guilty of themselves

Tags: single-word-requests

This is similar to a previous question (... accuses another of doing something which they did ...) but more generalized. Two examples:
A German woman athlete falsely accused other women athletes of being men; it transpired that she was a man. Similarly, Trump repeatedly called Clinton "Crooked Hillary." Who was the real crook? In my personal experience, this is a very common phenomenon. One suggestion was "Projecting." Does this imply deflection?  One conclusion to the original question was that a new word needed to be coined. I propose the word "Gasblagging." (see Gaslighting and Blagging.)

Comment: Your question is welcome. Some more information will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: As it stands, this reads more like a statement than a question. The purpose of this site is to collect expert answers to real questions about the English language. You are welcome to answer your own question, but your answer should be posted separately in an answer box, not included in the question. That way your answer can be reviewed and voted on separately from the question.

Comment: I vaguely recall that some years ago the Oxford Dictionary carried the entry "Spenlow & Jorkins", the meaning of which was given as something like "The art of blaming someone else for one's own wrongdoings". Spenlow & Jorkins are characters from Dickens novel "David Copperfield".

Answer (score 2):

While I vote +1 for "gasblagging", the common term is **projecting**.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection

**Psychological projection** is a theory in psychology in which the human ego defends itself against unconscious impulses or qualities (both positive and negative) by denying their existence in themselves while attributing them to others.

The origin of the theory is *Sigmund Freud*

Comment: If the action was involuntary, I would agree with "projection", but does it apply when it is a deliberate technique?

Comment: @Royforge, when it is used just as "projecting" it is a layman's version of the psychological condition with a much looser definition, so this is how it is commonly used. (I'm not sure the psychological term means that it is only unconscious behavior.)